# TypeError: connect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' during login FTP server using python

Tags: python

The below code is giving error of missing one positional arguement 'self'

````
   from ftplib import FTP

   # FTP Login Details ############################################################################
   server_ftp = "abc.azure.com"
   user_ftp = "qqqqqq"
   password_ftp = "xxxxx"
   port_ftp = 2500

   ################################################################################################
   FTP.connect(host=server_ftp, port=port_ftp)
   FTP.login(user=user_ftp, passwd=password_ftp)
   print('ftp server connected') ```
````

Answer (score 3):

The `FTP` is a class, you need to instanciate it

```
ftp1 = FTP()

ftp1.connect(host=server_ftp, port=port_ftp)
ftp1.login(user=user_ftp, passwd=password_ftp)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to instantiate `FTP` [class,](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) you can use:

```
ftp = FTP(source_address=(server_ftp, port_ftp),  user=user_ftp, passwd=password_ftp)
```